# Conditional writing in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have `Prolog` database with airplane schedules. Here is how it looks:

```
fly(id, from, to, days(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)).
```

As you can see there are 7 values in `days` predicate - from Monday to Sunday. What I want to do is to print every day, where value is `1`, but print it into just text. I was trying to use `if - else` statement, but in this case it doesn't work how it is supposed to:

```
(   
        A = 1 -> write(monday), nl;
        (
            B = 1 -> write(tuesday), nl;
            (
                C = 1 -> write(wednesday), nl;
                (
                    D = 1 -> write(thursday), nl;
                    (
                        E = 1 -> write(friday), nl;
                        (
                            F = 1 -> write(saturday), nl;
                            (
                                G = 1 -> write(sunday), nl
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

In example case it should print 4 days:

```
monday
wednesday
friday
sunday
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a way to do that, basically, you need to create 2 lists. First one is for your days, and the second one is for names of days. Then, you need to iterate them, but, because of fact that there are no `loop` constructions in Prolog, you have to do that using recursive function.

Here is how I have implemented it:

```
iterate_weeks([], _).
iterate_weeks([H|T], [X|Y]) :- H = 1, write(X), nl, iterate_weeks(T, Y).
iterate_weeks([H|T], [_|Y]) :- H = 0, iterate_weeks(T, Y).

print_fly_days(From, To):- 
    fly(_, From, To, _, _, days(A,B,C,D,E,F,G)),
    L = [A,B,C,D,E,F,G],
    T = [monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday],
    iterate_weeks(L, T).
```

Comment: "*there are no loop constructions in Prolog, you have to do that using recursive function.*" - \*blink\* like saying there's no potato so you have to eat fries. There's a name at the top, some code which is repeated, and you jump back to the top. That's how loops are structured and how they behave, becasue recursion is looping.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Nah recursion is not looping and you know it.

Comment: @TA_intern `"10 print "hello world", 20 goto 10` and `ten() { print "hello world"; ten()}` . I'm going to continue believing the second one is a loop unless you can explain a good reason for thinking it isn't.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler yeah I don't know it stops being a loop if the function has an argument; also, it stops being a loop when you run out of stack on a language like C; it also is not a loop in Python, despite raising the recursion depth to 1000. So in theory they are "same" for some definition of it but in practice there is a significant difference. The whole argument is a bit irrelevant though :-)

Comment: For python, try something like (not indented...) `def f(x): print x; f(x+1)` and call that with `f(0)`. Tell me what you see ;-)

Answer (score 1):

In APL, selecting from an array using a boolean array of indicators is the `compress` operation:

```
     1 0 1 0 1 0 1 / 'Mon' 'Tue' 'Wed' 'Thu' 'Fri' 'Sat' 'Sun'
┌→────────────────────────┐
│ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ ┌→──┐ │
│ │Mon│ │Wed│ │Fri│ │Sun│ │
│ └───┘ └───┘ └───┘ └───┘ │
└∊────────────────────────┘
```

I can't see that Prolog has anything that convenient, but you can:

```
day_name(days(1, _, _, _, _, _, _), mon).
day_name(days(_, 1, _, _, _, _, _), tue).
day_name(days(_, _, 1, _, _, _, _), wed).
day_name(days(_, _, _, 1, _, _, _), thu).
day_name(days(_, _, _, _, 1, _, _), fri).
day_name(days(_, _, _, _, _, 1, _), sat).
day_name(days(_, _, _, _, _, _, 1), sun).

days_names(Day, Names) :-
    findall(Name, day_name(Day, Name), Names).
```

e.g.

```
?- days_names(days(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), Names).
Names = [mon, wed, fri, sun]
```

---

Another option is `pairs_keys_values/3` with the bools and names to get pairs `[1-mon, 0-tue, 1-wed]`, filter the `1-_` with `include/3` then unpair them. It's fewer lines and avoids findall, but is not very clear.

Answer (score -2):

Using term-expansion, to conveniently map days to integers:

```
:- nb_setval(day_counter, 1).

% Silence warnings
:- discontiguous day_int/2.
:- discontiguous int_day/2.

% Don't actually need day_int for this example, but still nice to show
term_expansion(day(Day), [int_day(I, Day), day_int(Day, I)]) :-
    nb_getval(day_counter, I),
    I1 is I + 1,
    nb_setval(day_counter, I1).

day(monday).
day(tuesday).
day(wednesday).
day(thursday).
day(friday).
day(saturday).
day(sunday).

days7_names(Days7, DayNames) :-
    findall(I, arg(I, Days7, 1), Is),
    maplist(int_day, Is, DayNames).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- days7_names(day(0,1,0,1,0,0,1), Ns).
Ns = [tuesday, thursday, sunday].
```

Can simplify to:

```
day(monday).
day(tuesday).
day(wednesday).
day(thursday).
day(friday).
day(saturday).
day(sunday).

:-  bagof(D, day(D), Ds),
    forall(nth1(I, Ds, D), assertz(int_day(I, D))).

days7_names(Days7, DayNames) :-
    findall(I, arg(I, Days7, 1), Is),
    maplist(int_day, Is, DayNames).
```

Comment: If you are already going the long way around with term expansion, why not put the days of the week in a list, in the code, and expand that to a table of facts `day(1, monday). day(2, tuesday).` and so on?

Comment: Because term expansion is fun, and because manually adding a counter to facts is tedious.

Comment: My code is taking advantage of first-argument indexing on `int_day/2` (generated via term_expansion), as intended.

Comment: OK, you are right, I see it now. But why then write the day/1 table as a table at all? You could have written: `int_day(_). term_expansion(int_day(_), Clauses) :- findall(int_day(N, D), nth1(N, [mon, tue, wed, thu, fri, sat, sun], D), Clauses).` That's all, no need for anything else (try it!)

Comment: Thanks, that's convenient for small amounts of rules. SWI-Prolog requires that the `int_day(_).` be *below* the `term_expansion/2`.

Comment: Thank you for the correction, indeed it only works if it is below the expansion rule.

Answer (score -2):

A surprisingly interesting question and some terribly questionable answers.

You already have the "days of the week" as a "bitmask", in a way. You chose a term with arity 7 to hold it (this is very clean, nice!) and you chose 0 and 1 as the values. It could have been the atoms `false` and `true` or any other two atoms, really, but this is a matter of taste and irrelevant.

Now, you need to match the bitmask to a list of values. Why not use another term with arity 7 and use arg/3 to pick the value, instead of lists, as you did in your own answer? It is just easier. You also don't need recursion, you can use findall to make the list or just a forall/2 if you only need the side effect. Here are the two options:

```
days_mask_names(Days, Names) :-
    findall(N,
        (   arg(X, Days, 1),
            arg(X, names(monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday), N)
        ),
        Names).

print_day_names(Days) :-
    forall(arg(X, Days, 1),
        (   arg(X, names(monday, tuesday, wednesday, thursday, friday, saturday, sunday), N),
            format("~a~n", [N])
        )).
```

With those defined, I get:

```
?- days_mask_names(days(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1), Names).
Names = [monday, wednesday, friday, sunday].

?- print_day_names(days(1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1)).
monday
wednesday
friday
sunday
true.
```

Comment: This is taking the surprising opinion that days of the week aren't a standard, reusable thing that should be defined *once*, separately.

Comment: @brebs if you did it as `day(1, monday). day(2, tuesday).` and so on I would be fine with it. You could also start counting at different days depending on locale, then your table of facts needs another column.

Comment: `arg/3` nice, that's what I wanted when I was thinking "nth but for terms would be useful for this".

Comment: @brebs and this was so strange I didn't even want to comment on it :-) yes the days of the week are not standard: languages, start of the week Sun or Mon and so on. What we need here is a mechanism to chose from one vector based on false/true in another vector. This is what the APL code in the other question is about. In R you use a vector of booleans as subscript to the vector of values: `my_values[my_bools]`. So how to do this in Prolog?

Comment: SWI-specific use of `arg/3`. With `between(1,7,X)`... it works everywhere.